# Fail to use Vitamio Android ffmpeg library: cannot locate '__aeabi_llsl'

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am following exactly the [instruction of vitamio to build the ffmpeg library on Android](https://github.com/yixia/FFmpeg-Android).

Compilation works, and I get libffmpeg.so, as well as several static libraries, such as libavcodec.a, libavformat.a, etc. I copied libffmpeg.so, as well as other lib*.a (in case I will use lib*.a later) in the jin folder.

Then I use it in the jni part of my Android ffmpeg application.
The jni part works independently in C++.

In Android.mk, I tried different settings, but there are always error.
The Android.mk settings are:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include /android-opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := native_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-arm/usr/lib  -L$(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lffmpeg
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ljnigraphics -lm -lz -ldl -lgcc
```

The errors are:

```
04-16 19:16:46.998: E/AndroidRuntime(10375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 19:16:46.998: E/AndroidRuntime(10375): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1963]:    69 could not load needed library 'libffmpeg.so' for 'libnative_sample.so' (load_library[1105]: Library 'libffmpeg.so' not found)
```

But libffmpeg.so is in the folder.

Then I use another setting:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lavformat  -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil  -lswresample
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lgcc -llog -ljnigraphics -lm -lz -ldl
```

Now the error is different, is:

```
04-16 19:19:29.777: D/dalvikvm(10419): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.andrvideoprocess/lib/libnative_sample.so 0x4051cb60
04-16 19:19:29.787: E/AndroidRuntime(10419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 19:19:29.787: E/AndroidRuntime(10419): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1312]:    69 cannot locate '__aeabi_llsl'...
```

I tried several different orders of these libraries, it outputs the same error information.

I go to the folder: $(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-arm/usr/lib
(i.e. /usr/src/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib)
find out that there is no libgcc.a

I go to a toolchain folder (I built according halfninja Android + ffmpeg instruction), "android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni/toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/armv7-a", type the command:

```
$ nm libgcc.a > output.txt
```

I find the __aeabi_llsl in the following information:

```
_ashldi3.o:
00000000 t $a
0000000c N $d
00000000 T __aeabi_llsl
00000000 T __ashldi3
```

So then I include the below in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni/toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/armv7-a
```

The compile again.
The same error:
Cannot load library:

```
reloc_library[1312]:    69 cannot locate '__aeabi_llsl'...
```

Help!!

Comment: Problem is related to libgcc.a and it is order in linking but I don't understand why you add `-lgcc`. Build system should already link libgcc.a (static version) for you. Start with removing that, do a clean build.

Comment: Thanks. I removed -lgcc, and cleaned build the project, and then run the project. Exactly the same error. And btw, why cannot I use libffmpeg.so?

Comment: Check the logs, if possible kernel. That may give a clue.

Comment: The reason libffmpeg.so does not work is that the link was not successful. Let me figure it out later on. If I use lib*.a, NDK wants to locate __aeabi_llsl. Does that mean I just can't simply use lib*.a, since they were created not using the option '-Wl,--no-undefined'?

Comment: you can use static libraries, if NDK wants to locate `llsl` you can add libgcc.a as the first item in linking then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure it out.
For some reason, lib*.a can not be used here.
(Although I found a version by churnalbs used it, I guessed he used a different ndk, possibly ndk5rc)

So I compile *.o to libffmpeg.so, and use PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY in Android.mk (for how to use it, see ndk doc)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg_VITAMIO_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libffmpeg_VITAMIO.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ffmpeg_VITAMIO_prebuilt
```

And also I need to add the below in java.

```
System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg_VITAMIO_prebuilt");
```

Now, compiling works.